# Custom chrome cast ambient wallpapper plugin

Tags: google-cast

Is it possible to develop custom plugin to display content on the chrome cast idle screen, such as displaying photos from another source than google photos?

Answer (score 0):

If your question pertains to a simple plugin to hook up directly to your chromecast to change its behaviour, then no, I only know of the [settings that are available on Google Home](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6080931?hl=en).

However, if you are developing your own app to cast with, then it would be possible. You would need to develop a [custom web receiver](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-receiver#0), and then use [this ui guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver/customize_ui) to style it accordingly. Then, simply cast with [your own developed app](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers). Besides casting, you do not need to do anything.